# Existing Java package does not satisfy dependency during package installation

Tags: java, arduino

I have Oracle/Sun JDK 7 installed and alternatives setup. When I try to install Arduino IDE, it says

```
$ sudo apt-get install arduino
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ax25-node libax25 openbsd-inetd
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless extra-xdg-menus icedtea-7-jre-jamvm java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libjna-java
  openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib ttf-dejavu-extra tzdata-java
Suggested packages:
  equivs libjna-java-doc icedtea-7-plugin sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  arduino ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless extra-xdg-menus icedtea-7-jre-jamvm java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libjna-java
  openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib ttf-dejavu-extra tzdata-java
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
Need to get 45.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 68.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

I do not know how to solve this. I do not want another JDK/JRE installed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package arduino deppends of default-jre, which depends of opedjdk-7-jre:

```
apt-cache depends arduino default-jre
arduino
 |Depends: default-jre
  Depends: <java6-runtime>
    openjdk-6-jre
    default-jre
    openjdk-7-jre
  Depends: libjna-java
  Depends: librxtx-java
  Depends: arduino-core
  Recommends: extra-xdg-menus
  Recommends: policykit-1
default-jre
  Depends: default-jre-headless
  Depends: openjdk-7-jre
```

Hence, you are doomed to use openjdk.

Answer (score 1):

So its simple.. First remove your existing `java` packages then `clean` your system, and then try installing again..

These steps would solve your issue, run it in a series.:

- Removing java and all dependent packages.

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get --purge remove openjdk-7*
  sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-7*
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -f install
  ```
- Then finally install `arduino`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install arduino
  ```

Reply if something goes wrong..